# Does JIRA 4.0 license work for JIRA 5.1?

Tags: jira

JIRA upgrade from 4.0.x to JIRA 5.1.3 - will the same running license work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jira licence includes 12 months of maintenance (updates/support) , during that time you can update for free without purchasing a new licence. After those 12 months you can use your Jira freely, but you **cannot** upgrade it. To learn more have a look at the [Jira's licensing information](http://www.atlassian.com/licensing/jira).

A JIRA commercial/academic license entitles you to: (as for Jira 5.0)

- Deploy a single instance of JIRA in a production environment on 1 server
  Unlimited projects and issues
- Perpetual JIRA use
- Software maintenance for 12 months - including all updates and online support (from Sydney, Australia and San Francisco, USA during local business hours)
- Full source code (under a developer source license which allows for broad customization)
- Licensing fees are quoted per number of 'active users'. An active user in JIRA is by definition any user account in the system with the "JIRA Users" global permission, i.e. anyone who can log in.  Unlimited 'anonymous users' are permitted on all licenses.